# JVM argument as a form action link in jsp dynamically

Tags: java, jsp, jstl

i am using jvm argument in TOMCAT as a `-DshopMaintenanceURL="https://shop-maintanance.com/shop/"`. here i want to use this value for the form action in a jsp

`<form action="https://shop-maintanance.com/shop/" method="POST" id="apForm">`

I am reading this argument in my java file

```
    public static String getShopMaintenanceURL() {
        String url = System.getProperty("shopMaintenanceURL");
        if(url !=null)
            return url;
        else
           return null;
}
```

i can use this url in my jsp page as config.getShopMaintenanceURL in my jsp page. (Here config is the object of the above java class).

`<form action="https://shop-maintanance.com/shop/" method="POST" id="apForm">`

i need to set the link as dynamically for the above form action. any ideas??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`config` is reserved word in JSP (it means `javax.servlet.ServletConfig`). So you should write:

```
<form action="<%=configObj.getShopMaintenanceURL()%>" method="POST" id="apForm"></form>
```

`configObj` is the java class you wrote.